# Как сделать чтобы SelectedItem в ListBox возвращал значение, а не System.Windows.Collections...?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, visual-studio-2017, listbox

В одном окне при нажатии на кнопку берется значение из ListBox (`lb1.SelectedItem.ToString()`) и записывается в `Properties.Settings...ItemS`. При старте другого окна берется значение из `Properties.Settings...ItemS` и записывается в label, но показывается впоследствии это значение как `System.Windows.Collections...`. Как использовать текст, а не `System.Windows.Collections...`?

```
//Это код получения выделенного текста
Properties.Settings.Default.ItemS = lb1.SelectedItem.ToString();
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

//Это код записи полученного текста в label
PrevSec.Content = Properties.Settings.Default.ItemS;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется [преобразование типов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions). Подходит как для базовых типов(`int`, `byte` и т.п.), так и для экземпляров классов.

```
//Это код получения выделенного текста
Properties.Settings.Default.ItemS = ((ListBoxItem)lb1.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

//Это код записи полученного текста в label
PrevSec.Content = Properties.Settings.Default.ItemS;
```